# Apache ( OHS 12 c) for managing keep-alive sessions and provide a throttle for WebLogic protection

Tags: apache-2.2, throttling

I need to use OHS 12C ( apache 2.2) for throttling purpose.I'm using OHS as proxy and forwarding request to weblogic server.
The requirement is to limit the concurrent connection to weblogic server to 512 and if OHS get more than 512 request then put those requests in backlog queue. Once the app server is done processing those 512 concurrent connections( hence OHS is done with 512 connections) then have OHS send those requests residing in backlog queue.

As a solution, I'm thinking to use httpd.worker MPM and limit the concurrent connection to OHS by setting "MaxClient" to 512.
Now there are some concern with monitoring.
1) how can we monitor number of sessions to OHS ?
2) how can we monitor keep-alive sessions ? - I'm going to use mod-status for this purpose.
3)how can we throttle the in-flight count while allowing the keep-alive sessions to grow to their required depth ?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure workmanger to limit concurrent requests refer below link:

http://www.slideshare.net/jambay/weblogic-server-work-managers-and-overload-protection

Or else you can use max-in-memory-sessions parameter to limit sessions check this :

http://www.munzandmore.com/2010/ora/weblogic-11g-overload-protection-in-the-cloud